# MySQL trigger update - values of updated row?

Tags: mysql

I was wondering wether or not it is possible for a Trigger to get the value of the row that triggered it? So that when i update a row in table X, it will insert a new row into table Y but use some values from table X.

Is there a way to achieve this? So that a triggering SQL sentence can fetch data of the row that triggered the trigger, or am i better off just using 2 queries?

Also, is there any way to fetch all different names in a table? Say i have a table with a column called "Names", and i want to select all names that are unique? So if i have:
Bob, Claire, Bob, Charlie

it will select: Bob, Claire, Charlie
And of thus not returning 2 bobs.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NEW` to relate to the triggered record

```
insert into Y (colY)
select NEW.colX
```

To the 2nd point

Either use `distinct`

```
select distinct name from your_table
```

or group

```
select name from your_table group by name
```

Comment: cool, thanks. Any chance u can answer my second question as well? Then i will chose your answer.

Was asking if you could get all unique names (see question).

Comment: Sweet, that did it. Thanks a lot mate. will accept in 8 min :)